# Can i use CGo on Google App Engine?

Tags: c, google-app-engine, go

So I was using CGo for a number crunching web app and it happens that CGo seems faster. Is there any that I can use CGo on Google App Engine Go runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.  CGo is not supported yet, and perhaps never will.  This is `PaaS` after all and they need to isolate the platform.  But you never know.  Perhaps a restricted version.

Comment: Thanks @Mario Rossi for the quick help. If a restricted CGo is implemented it would be great for long running background tasks.

Comment: @RoneyThomas Until/unless that happens, you can use Google Compute Engine (which now has micro instances) to run whatever you want, including a cgo app, and use the task queue and datastore APIs to get data from/to the appengine app.  Since it's all within Google's network, it's super snappy.

Comment: @KyleLemons  Very good point!  I limited myself to answer the specific question and didn't think "out of the box" :-( .

Answer (score 3):

It is supported on App engine Go 1.11
https://gist.github.com/apstndb/456e47ce0dcca191d967aefed1320b92

I know it is an old question but it is still in top results, so just added for any one searching for it now